# How to prove that the time complexity of this algorithm is O($\sqrt{N}$)?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, runtime-analysis

```
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 1; sum <= n; i++) {
      sum += i;
  }
```

If I assumed that $N = 100$, the loop will run $13$ steps, which is almost the square root of $N$, if $N = 10000$, the loop will run $141$ steps, which is almost the square root of $N$, but I don't know how to prove that, I only know it by intuition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The loop iterates $k$ times, where $k$ is minimal such that $\sum_{i=1}^k i>n$.  We know that $\sum_{i=1}^k i = \tfrac12k(k+1)$, so you just need to solve for $k$.